# Admob Large Banner Position

Tags: objective-c, xcode, admob

I'm trying to use Large Banner instead of Smart Banner but I can't make it stay at the bottom. I'm using this code for the smart banner and it stays at the bottom but doesn't work for the large banner. When I change from kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait to kGADAdSizeLargeBanner, the banner moves to the top.

```
     _bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];

    _bannerView_.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - _bannerView_.frame.size.height , self.view.frame.size.width, _bannerView_.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code.

```
// Initialize the banner docked to the bottom of the screen.
// We start in a portrait orientation so use kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait.
  CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                               self.view.frame.size.height -
                               CGSizeFromGADAdSize(
                                   kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height);

  _bannerView_ = [[[GADBannerView alloc]
                    initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
                            origin:origin] autorelease];

//Continue rest of initialization here
```

Reference : http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/06/keeping-smart-banner-docked-to-bottom.html

Comment: My code above works for smart banners, it just doesn't work for Large Banners, I tried your code and it doesn't work for Large banners either.